# Amsart, natbib and endnotes incompatible?

Tags: natbib, amsart, endnotes

I can't get the document class `amsart` and the packages `natbib` and `endnotes` to work together.

As a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}

\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{endnotes}

\begin{document}

bla\endnote{bla}

\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

Either change the document class to (e.g.) `article`, remove `\usepackage[round]{natbib}` or remove `\theendnotes`, and things work. But the three together result in:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<write> ...keUppercase {Notes}}{\let \@bibauthor
\@empty \let \@bibjournal ...
l.13 \end{document}
```

(I have here taken citations and bibliography out, but that makes no difference.)

Is there any way to fix this, or are the three simply not compatible? (I made sure I use the latest versions.)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Nice minimal example!

Comment: With `\usepackage{enotez}` and `\printendnotes` instead of `\theendnotes` it compiles.

Comment: Thanks @egreg, `enotez` works perfect!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `natbib` leaves `\@temptokena` “dirty”; this is usually not a problem, but it is in case `amsart` is used, because it writes also entries declared with `\section*` in the table of contents and this is the reason of the error.

Workaround:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}

\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{endnotes}

\begin{document}

bla\endnote{bla}

\begingroup\csname @temptokena\endcsname{}% empty off \@temptokena
\theendnotes
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

However, there is a more recent package, `enotez`, that can be used as a replacement of `endnotes`; it's much more customizable, by the way.

Instead of `\usepackage{endnotes}` type `\usepackage{enotez}` (and consult its documentation). Instead of `\theendnotes`,

```
\printendnotes
```

should be used.